# Active Record object loaded from database is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord object that I load from database.

When I call `valid?` on this object it returns `false` due to a rails unique constraint not met, at least so the validation says.

I checked the database schema and the unique field also has an index defined, so the uniqueness is also ensured on the database level.

What is going on here and how is this even possible in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You should check **@object.errors.inspect** for inspection of what's going on and then fix accordingly.

Also it does matter that when are you checking the validity of an object i.e. before save or after save.

The more elegant way is to use `@object.save!`

Ruby should tell you what went wrong during the attempt to save the object.

Comment: The error was, that the index on the database was not unique, but I thought it was which added to my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have unique indexes defined on your database tables, this is what happens!

To be a bit more elaborate: I thought the database had a unique index on the column, but that turned out to be a 'regular' index.
The problem occurred, because at some point in the application, the model got saved without validating it first. Which led to non unique entries in the database. By calling `valid?` triggers the rails internal routine that checks for uniqueness (however that is implemented) , which returned false, correctly.

Lesson learned: Always make sure to add a unique index at the database level.